# How to compile OpenCV software on Raspberry?

Tags: c, opencv, c++

I want compile an OpenCV program on Raspberry, the problem is that I didn't figure out how to do so. I installed OpenCV following this [guide](http://robertcastle.com/2014/02/installing-opencv-on-a-raspberry-pi/).

```
$ pkg-config --modversion opencv
2.4.1
```

OpenCV can be found in **/home/pi/opencv-2.4.10**

I use code::blocks, I found several guide on how to use that on linux in general, but not on Raspberry. One [guide on how to set up code::Blocks](http://answers.opencv.org/question/25642/how-to-compile-basic-opencv-program-in-c-in-ubuntu/) helped me to understand, but I didn't solve the issue because despite I set compiler and linker path, in linker settings I have anything.

- I used as compiler path: **/home/pi/opencv-2.4.10/include/openc**v and **/home/pi/opencv-2.4.10/include/opencv**
- and as linker path: **/home/pi/opencv-2.4.10/build/lib**

What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: what is the error message and what is the command you are using to generate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I have to add manually all the libraries in /home/pi/opencv-2.4.10/build/lib, simply go to linker settings and click on add button and select all them.